# Variable number of arguments in generic class in Java for callback function

Tags: java

I have a generic class for grpc requests like this:

```
abstract class GenericRunnable<T> {
    abstract public void callback(T result);
}
```

The goal is to extend it like this:

```
abstract class MyRunnable extends GenericRunnable<String, Integer, String> {
    ...
}
```

And then I can implement an anonymous class of MyRunnable with:

```
@Override
public void callback(String a, Integer b, String c) {
    ...
}
```

Is something like this obtainable? Since each grpc request has different return values it would be nice to have this. For example one request returns the age, the other returns first and last name, etc.

The alternative is to define a `returnClass` for each `MyRunnable` and pass it to `<T>`.

Comment: what is your intention here as it looks like a kind of command pattern
are you aware of it ?
In command pattern instead of overriding method you can create object which will carry operation more details here
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command

there is java example at the bottom

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that what I'm doing already? GenericRunnable<T> is a a generic. MyRunnable is some specific implementation of command. I then pass this runnable into a class that call the generic command execute, and at the end calls its callback (which is what I have here). The problem I have is that the callback can have multiple arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String, Integer, String` is three parameters while your `GenericRunnable` works with one.

Wrap them up into a class

```
class ABC {
    private String a;
}
```

and use that class as a generic parameter.

```
class MyRunnable extends GenericRunnable<ABC> {
    @Override
    public void callback(ABC request) {
        String a = request.getA();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing for more complex cases, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can `scala.Tuple22` to have parameterized input upto 22 parameterized class

```
import scala.Tuple22;
import scala.Tuple3;

abstract class GenericRunnable<T> {
    abstract public void callback(T result);
}

class MyRunnable3Param extends GenericRunnable<Tuple3<String,Integer,String>> { // Class with 3 Parameters

    @Override
    public void callback(Tuple3<String,Integer,String> tuple) {

    }
}
... 
class MyRunnable22Param extends GenericRunnable<Tuple22<String,Integer,String...>> { // Class with 22 Parameters

    @Override
    public void callback(Tuple22<String,Integer,String...> tuple) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using custom classes though.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be possible, though you could wrap a sequence of the types into some container or object:

```
public class MyRunnable extends GenericRunnable<Triple<String, Integer, String>> {
    @Override
    public void callback(Triple<String, Integer, String> triplet) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // ...
        callback(new Triple(string1, int1, string2));
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a possible solution but I don't think it's as flexible so I didn't use it.